# Why sscanf is taking more than desired value in C?

Tags: c, scanf

Why sscanf is taking more than the desired value?

Sample code:

```
int main()
{
    char *str="a:b:c:d:g:s:d";
    int a[4]={0};
    int ret;
    ret = sscanf(str,"%x:%x:%x:%x",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3]); /*It prints 4 but in input I have given 7 values(a,b,c,d,g,s,d)*/
    if(ret==4)
    {
        printf("success\n");// it prints success anyways!
    }
    return 0
}
```

I wanted to go inside the if condition only if the *str contains 4 octets(a:b:c:d - only Hex values).

NOTE: If I give less than 4 octets it isn't going inside the if condition.

Comment: after doing the normal `sscanf()` do an additional one; if it succeeds then print error...

Comment: `sscanf()` doesn't have to use the whole string.  You gave 4 valid hex numbers (`0x0A`, `0x0B`, `0x0C`, and `0x0D` separated by colons as the format required.  The residue is unparsed.  You can use `%n` to find out how far the parsing progressed.  Remember, `sscanf()` is non-destructive — it does not modify the string that it is processing.  That means. you can rescan the string with different formats if you wish, or if you need to because the first attempt didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string didn't give seven values since "g" and "s" are not valid hexadecimal values. So fix that first:

```
char *str="a:b:c:d:e:f:1";
```

Then try to read more than four values:

```
ret = sscanf(str,"%x:%x:%x:%x:%x",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3],&ret);
```

Now, if there are more than four values, this code will read five of them, and the `if` will fail. I re-used `ret` because the assignment of the return value is guaranteed to happen after. But if that scares or confuses you, you can do this:

```
int dummy;
ret = sscanf(str,"%x:%x:%x:%x:%x",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3],&dummy);
```

Comment: what if there is only 4 values in the string? will `sscanf()` even return?

Comment: @user12986714 It will return 4 since it will only read 4 values.

Comment: `dummy` remains as it was when only 4 are scanned.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The point of dummy is just to ensure that 5 is returned if there are 5 values. The idea is not to ever look at its value.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz dummy is returning 0 even if there are 4 or more than 4 values.

Comment: @kavinhuh There's no reason to look at dummy's value. It's only purpose is that `sscanf` requires a valid pointer that it can use. If `ret` is 4, `dummy` was never filled with a value. If `ret` is anything other than 4, that's an error condition and there's no reason to look at any values.